# how can I make a word fatter and make a line break in my string in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to make a line break into my string and make a word fatter but \n or \r doesn't work. I work with react and next.js.

the word I want to make fatter is "studio", and I want to make a line break after "reves."
Words are in "description".

Someone can help me please?

I use a general reusable block containing a title, a description and an image, then I call this block, as on the code I put here, and I add what I want
this is this block:

```
export interface ITheTeamBlockProps {
  title?: string;
  job?: string;
  description?: string;
  img?: {url: string, alt?: string};
  className?: string;
}
export interface ITheTeamBlockState{

}
export default class TheTeamBlock extends React.Component<ITheTeamBlockProps, ITheTeamBlockState>{
  render(){
    const { title, job, description, img, className } = this.props;
    return <>
    <div className={className + 'theTeam-block'}>
        <div className="theTeam-block__title">{title}</div>
        <div className="theTeam-block__job">{job}</div>
        {/* <div className="theTeam-block__image-box">
          <img src={img.url} alt={img.alt}/>
        </div> */}
        <div className="theTeam-block__description">{description}</div>
    </div>
    </>
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import BannerBottomBlock, { IBannerBottomBlockProps } from '../banners/bannerMiddleBottom';

interface ITeamBannerBottomBlockProps {
  title?: string;
}
interface ITeamBannerBottomBlockState{
  bannerBlockInfos: IBannerBottomBlockProps[]
}
export default class TeamBannerBottomBlock extends React.Component<ITeamBannerBottomBlockProps, ITeamBannerBottomBlockState>{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        bannerBlockInfos: [
          {
            title: "Le premier lien du studio, celui d'une amitié.", 
            description: `Avant même d'être un studio, Ben&Jo est une histoire d'amitié solidifiée par une passion commune, celle d'aider les autres à accomplir leurs rêves. Ainsi cette agence de communication s'est fondée sur les valeurs d'une amitié comme la transparence, l'honnêteté, la compassion, le partage et l'amour !`, 
            img: { url : "/img/pages-cible/team/story-first-link.svg"},
          },
        ]
      }
    }
    render(){
      const { bannerBlockInfos } = this.state;
    return <>
        <div className="team__bannerBottom">
            { bannerBlockInfos && bannerBlockInfos.map((item, index) => {
                    return <BannerBottomBlock key={"team__bannerBottom-block_" + index } 
                        {...item} className="team__bannerBottom-block"/>
                })
            }
        </div>
    </>
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd normally use HTML in your data value and apply CSS to it. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I use a general reusable block containing a title, a description and an image, then I call this block, as on the code I put here, and I add what I want

Comment: If you have control over the text content, you could add HTML to your strings (title, description) to stylize their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use some tag (here i used <> </>) instead of quotations around your string and put `<br/>` where you want line break.

if by fatter you mean bold, use `<strong>` tag

```
description: <>Avant même d'être un <strong>studio</strong>, Ben&Jo est une histoire d'amitié solidifiée par une passion commune, celle d'aider les autres à accomplir leurs rêves.<br/> Ainsi cette agence de communication s'est fondée sur les valeurs d'une amitié comme la transparence, l'honnêteté, la compassion, le partage et l'amour !</>
```

[See Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Malf1.png)

Comment: thank you I must add {} after description?: or I have an error but it's ok.